# How to automatically adjust to long words in drop down menus?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

http://jsfiddle.net/a2gRf/

I have this jsfiddle here and as you can see if you type a longer menu name it gets clipped in the little tiny container, what I want to achieve is to automatically make the container larger if I input a longer word in the menu, i don't know if this is possible or not or do I have to just make all of them 300px wide?

code below

```
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Parent 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="selected">Parent 02</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="selected">Item 02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 03</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 000000000000000003</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 04</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 05</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 06</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 07</a></li>
    </ul>            
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 04</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Css

```
 body {font-family:arial; font-size:11px;}
.clear {clear:both}    
/* remove the list style */
#nav {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}    

    /* make the LI display inline */
    /* it's position relative so that position absolute */
    /* can be used in submenu */
    #nav li {
        float:left;
        display:block;
        width:100px;
        background:#ccc;
        position:relative;
        z-index:500;
        margin:0 1px;
    }

    /* this is the parent menu */
    #nav li a {
        display:block;
        padding:8px 5px 0 5px;
        font-weight:700;
        height:23px;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#fff;
        text-align:center;
        color:#333;
    }
    #nav li a:hover {
        color:#fff;
    }

    /* you can make a different style for default selected value */
    #nav a.selected {
        color:#f00;
    }

        /* submenu, it's hidden by default */
        #nav ul {
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            display:none;
            margin:0 0 0 -1px;
            padding:0;
            list-style:none;
        }

        #nav ul li {
            width:100px;
            float:left;
            border-top:1px solid #fff;
        }

        /* display block will make the link fill the whole area of LI */
        #nav ul a {
            display:block;
            height:15px;
            padding: 8px 5px;
            color:#666;
        }

        #nav ul a:hover {
            text-decoration:underline;    
        }
/* fix ie6 small issue */
/* we should always avoid using hack like this */
/* should put it into separate file : ) */
*html #nav ul {
    margin:0 0 0 -2px;
}
```

jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {    

    $('#nav li').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(100);
        },
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(100);            
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: if you want to hide overflowing data use `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the `min-width:100px;` instead in your `#nav li { ...` class.
it should work.

Comment: You have no idea how happy I am right now! Thanks, this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

just change that 100px width rule from

```
width:100px;
```

to

```
min-width:100px;
```

then css will automatically size it for you, and make sure that all the parent li items are at least 100px wide.

[Working JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a2gRf/1/)

But beware, this won't prevent your entire ul from overflowing if you have too may menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Delete width property, like this:

```
#nav li {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  /*width:100px;*/
  background:#ccc;
  position:relative;
  z-index:500;
  margin:0 1px;
}
```